# Do traded cities produce unhappiness?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do cities received through a trade have any special properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/do-cities-received-through-a-trade-have-any-special-properties)

Do they create unhappiness like a puppeted/occupied city? Or do they act like a normal city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, gaining a city through trade typically acts exactly as if you had attacked and captured it except the population doesn't reduce, no buildings are destroyed and you don't get the gold added to your treasure for pillaging it.